# Limit Azure Key Vault access to Web App and Function

Tags: azure, security, azure-keyvault

I created an Azure Web App and an Azure Function as well as an Azure Key Vault. I created an `access policy` to only allow the system assigned identities from the Web App and Azure Function access to the Key Vault. But it still feels quite open if "All networks, including the internet" can reach the Key Vault. How can I simply limit the network access to my own Resource Groups? I was not able to find a how-to for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Key Vault has it's own firewall that is disabled by default, you can enable it to allow traffic for:

- Trusted services
- Static IP addresses
- VNETS

If your Web App and Azure Function are on specific VNETS then you can lock it down to only allow traffic from that VNET.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/network-security

Answer (score 0):

this simply means that the keyvault allows networking requests from all the possible locations in the world, you can control it to some extent, but you cannot limit access to a specific paas service, unless you tie the service to the vnet and then you can limit the access to that vnet.

web apps and functions can be tied to a vnet I'm quite sure that with v1 version that won't help with securing this scenario, but I'm not sure about v2, that might work

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you clarify what you refer to with v1 and v2?

Comment: vnet integration v1 and v2

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned you can definitely enable your [AKV's firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/network-security) to further secure your vault and limit the access to that VNET.

Your vault is also secure even with the "All networks, including the internet.." prompt. This is because in order to access your Key Vault, a user, app, or identity will need to be added to your Key Vault's management plane (RBAC), and data plane (access policies) to view anything within your vault.

For more info:
[Management plane and Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault#management-plane-and-azure-rbac)
[Data plane and access policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault#data-plane-and-access-policies)